# html agility section selecting

Tags: c#, html, tags, html-agility-pack

I need to get the HTML in between 2 section tags like this:

```
<section class="image-section">
//images here...
</section>
```

I am using HTML Agility to do this and though this would work:

```
HtmlNode sec = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='image-section'")
```

but this does not. How would I get the HTML snippet I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we have following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <section class="image-section">
         <img src="image1.jpg">
         <img src="image2.jpg">
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is a code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var html = File.ReadAllText(@"d:/my.html");

            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

            HtmlNodeCollection sections = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='image-section']");
            var section = sections.FirstOrDefault();
            if (section != null)
            {
                foreach (var imgElement in section.Elements("img"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(imgElement.OuterHtml);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg">
```

Comment: This worked thanks! It was because I was using HTML Node instead of node collection I think.

Comment: How would I use section.Elements() to select all <a href="foo"> tags?

Comment: @Bluehand the same way I guess. Here is a [**link**](https://i.imgur.com/UeQf84Z.png). Just don't forget to close `a` tag.